# RESTKit: BaseURL & Path Pattern

Tags: json, google-maps, ios7, restkit, restkit-0.20

iOS7 & RESTKit 0.20.3

Below is the URL that I need to hit to get a response from Google Maps APIs (I changed the key):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=coffee&sensor=true&key=1234&location=0.000000,0.000000&radius=100.000000

When I type the URL above in the browser, I get a JSON back (200 OK)

`input` is the search string the user provides.  I have hard-coded it into the URL above.

The following is what I have tried and get a 404 error:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/placeautocomplete/json?input=%@&sensor=true&key=1234&location=0.000000,0.000000&radius=100.000000", [input stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                       pathPattern:@""
                                                                                           keyPath:@"predictions" statusCodes:statusCodeSet];
```

I have also tried the following that gives an error `Code=1001 "No response descriptors match the response loaded."` :

```
NSIndexSet *statusCodeSet = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);
RKMapping *mapping = [TBSRESTMappingProvider googleAutoCompleteMapping];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=coffee&sensor=true&key=1234&location=0.000000,0.000000&radius=100.000000"]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                   pathPattern:@""
                                                                                       keyPath:@"predictions" statusCodes:statusCodeSet];

RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                                    responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
```

1. What's the best practice to provide the complete URL without hard-coding the `input` `sensor` `location` `key` and `radius` ?
2. How can I fix `Code=1001 "No response descriptors match the response loaded."`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL path that you request needs to match against the path pattern you supply to the response descriptor. If you want to work the way you are then set the path pattern to `nil` (which matches everything).

Best practice would generally be to use an `RKObjectManager` instance and call `getObjectsAtPath:parameters:success:failure:` and passing a dictionary of parameters that should be appended to the request URL (built from the base URL, path and parameters).

Comment: Thanks.  I have been Googling an example that appends the request URL.  Can you please point me to one?

Comment: What do you mean 'append'? You set the base URL on the object manager, pass the path and the parameters to the `get` method...

Comment: Do I set the baseurl in getObjectsAtPath:baseURL 
BaseURL = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?

For Parameters, I'll have a dictionary.  'input' : 'whatever'  ?

Comment: You set the base URL when you create the `RKObjectManager` instance.